# One by Wacom Pen Tablet installing in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wacom

I am trying to install One by Wacom Pen Tablet CTL-472 in Ubuntu 17.10. In the system settings it says 'No Tablet Detected'. I have tried all options that i could lay my hands on on the net. its working fine in windows 10. 
thanks in advance

Comment: @SajidMubashir wanted to comment that Wacom sent them [this wiki link](http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) with the comment "This is an open source project which is heavily supported by Wacom - e.g. with developers working in the Wacom Driver Development team."

Comment: The device figures in the Device IDs list but it says that CTL-472 and CTL-672 are not supported in Linux, input-wacom and libwacom. When can i expect it to be supported.

Comment: @Satyam Just an update if somebody else reads your comment: now both are supported (as of 2020-10-14).

Answer (score -1):

I am using CTL-472 in Ubuntu 18.04. And after I following the instructions on this page [to install a new driver](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/wiki/Installing-input-wacom-from-source), the tablet can be detected and works well now.

**Prerequisites**

Before building, you'll need to ensure the necessary dependencies have been installed on your system:

```
sudo apt  install build-essential autoconf linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

**Download**

In general, you should simply download and untar the latest release from the [releases page](https://github.com/linuxwacom/input-wacom/releases). If, however, you need to build a development version of the driver you will need to install and use the "git" tool to clone a copy of our repository. The developer should provide you with a git command to perform the necessary clone.

Build / Install

Open a terminal and navigate into the extracted/cloned input-wacom directory. Next, copy and paste the following command to build and install the driver. If you get a "Build Failed" message at the end if your output, please contact the linuxwacom developers for support.

```
if test -x ./autogen.sh; then ./autogen.sh; else ./configure; fi && make && sudo make install || echo "Build Failed"
```

**Module Loading**

The updated driver should automatically load after rebooting the system. You can verify the version number of the loaded kernel module by running the following command. Version numbers like "v2.00" indicate that the stock kernel module is still in use. A version number like "v2.00-0.38.0" indicates that version 0.38.0 of the input-wacom driver is loaded. Consult the "Troubleshooting" section below if the version number does not match what you expect.

```
grep "" /sys/module/wacom*/version
```

or, if you do not have a tablet attached to the computer:

```
modinfo wacom | grep version
```

**Next Steps**

Upgrading both the kernel driver and the X driver to the same version is recommended. Please see the instructions for [updating the xf86-input-wacom driver](https://github.com/linuxwacom/xf86-input-wacom/wiki/Building-The-Driver).